# Why the Number class doesn't have methods like add() or negate()?

Tags: java, numbers

Well, this is a question about the Java design.

Why aren't there methods like `add()` and `negate()` on the `java.lang.Number` class, but there are on *some* of its subclasses?

I mean... there is no uniformity. I can use the `+` or `-` operators on `Float`, `Long` and other autoboxeable classes, and I can use `add()` and `negate()` on `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger` (which violates the SRP).

So if we are allowing those operations on `Byte`/`Short`/`Integer`/`Long` anyways (with autoboxing and operators), why not just add an `abstract Number negate()` and etc to `Number`?

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Because then you'd appear to be able to `add()` a Byte to a Double, and there isn't any real code to permit that.

Comment: You are still able to do that if you use the operator +, the boxing operations will handle that for you. `Byte b = 'b'; Double d = 3.14; d += b;`.

Comment: So why do you need the other?

Comment: Basically, uniformity and polymorphism.

Comment: And keep in mind that, despite what the docs would have you believe, Number was invented *after* its "primitive" subclasses.  There's a fair amount of luck involved in the fact that the subclasses resemble each other as much as they do.

Comment: Now thiiiis makes sense. Useful info. :)

Comment: @Hot Licks van you back that up? I've got the java 1.0.2 API here http://web.mit.edu/java_v1.0.2/www/javadoc/java.lang.Number.html#_top_ and it show number to be the superclass of Integer, Long, Float and Double

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt - I don't have any docs going back that far, and may be misremembering, I suppose.  I do know that the language was in a lot of flux back then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most importantly, to preserve backward compatibility.

These methods that you mention weren't in the first version of java.lang.Number, and they would need to be **abstract**.
Why abstract? Suppose you created your own `ComplexNumber` subclass of `Number` before it had a `negate()` method, and now a `negate()` method is added to `Number`. 
If the `negate()` method wasn't abstract, there should be a general implementation of it in `java.lang.Number`. What type of object should it return? There is no possible *good* decision for this. Should it be a `Double`, like this: `public Number negate() { return new Double(this.doubleValue()); }`? That would suddenly convert your ComplexNumber to a Double on a negate.

And adding **abstract** methods wouldn't work because it would break existing third-party subclasses of `Number`, so it would break backward compatibility.

Backward compatibility is the reason that a lot of possible API improvements that seem obvious now cannot be implemented.

Comment: Are there third-party subclasses of Number?

Comment: java.lang.Number is a public, non-final class. So, yes. You can check apache commons-lang and commons-math for some examples.

Answer (score 5):

I think the following *might* be the reason.

[`Number`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) is also a super-class of [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) and [`AtomicLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html).  If `Number` had an `add()` method these sub-classes would have had to implement it as well, which is impossible to do while preserving the atomicity.

Instead these two classes implement `addAndGet()` as a single atomic operation.

Comment: You got a really interesting point, but... the `add()` method in `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` classes doesn't change the object, returns a new one (so a `+` operator, not a `+=`). This probably could be implemented in `AtomicInteger` and `AtomicLong` as well.

Answer (score 5):

In a nutshell, it's because you do not know what type to return from your binary operations.

When you add two subclasses of `Number` of the same type, there's no doubt about the return type. However, operations on two `Number` implementations of different kind would create issues of multiple dispatch (i.e. each class would need to know how to deal with all other subclasses of `Number`).

That would be hard, but not impossible. What's impossible is dealing with user-defined subclasses of `Number`. Since `Number` is an interface, users are free to create their own implementations. Excluding them would be too inconsistent; including them is not possible, because library designers cannot know about them.

Answer (score 3):

My guess why:

The `Number` class is just the abstract base so you could refer to all numbers by some common type. I've so far not seen anyone do that.

The problem with e.g. `.negate()` is that it would have to return a `Number` or better the appropriate subtype since all numbers are immutable. It is questionable to begin with if such an functionality would be useful. The problem with e.g. `.add(Number other)` is even worse since that would allow to add numbers of different types. Compare http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem

The next point is that math operations on anything but `Big???` are much more efficient on primitives than on immutable Objects that need to create a new object for every operation. The idea was probably that you are not supposed to do math with objects unless it is impossible when big numbers can't be represented as primitives. Wrapper classes like `Float` should only be used in case you need an Object. (accidential mistakes like comparing `Float` with `==` also easily lead to programming errors.)

`Big???` simply need those methods, wrapped primitives don't because you can simply do math with primitives.

Answer (score 1):

`add` and `negate` exist on `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger` *because* you can't use `+` and `-`.

`+` and `-` only work on `Float` and `Long` because of autounboxing. It used to be the case that you would explicitly unbox the object, do the math with the unboxed primitives, and then rebox if necessary.